# Google Protobuf Empty List Showing Size 1

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am using Google Protobuf with Java. I am having problem with sending empty repeated string.

```
message OurPokemonMessage {
        ....
        repeated string learnableMoves = 10;
}
```

Now when I use Protobuf method to add a collection (which is empty) like this :

```
message.addAllLearnableMoves(someEmptyListOfString);
```

Now when I create a new List of String using this message I get one element in the list which is an Empty List.

This is how I create List of string using the message :

```
new ArrayList<>(message.getLearnableMovesList())
```

This array list contains an empty string element. So I debugged the message and evaluated 2 conditions and found weird results.

```
message.getLearnableMovesList()//clearly shows empty list

     (com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList) [] //Empty

message.getLearnableMovesList().size()//shows the size of list is 1
     (int) 1 //Size is 1
```

Has anyone faces any similar problems? Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Rather than showing us snippets, could you provide a [mcve]? That will make it much easier for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem with a smaller example but it doesn't in that case. Since I am using a complicated Protobuf structure and sending messages over the network, I am not exactly sure about how to provide a proper example :/

Comment: If you're struggling to reproduce it in a small example, it's likely it's a problem elsewhere which will be very hard for us to help with. Try copying your whole project and gradually removing bits until you've either found the problem or have a small example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realised later on that there was no issue with protobuf library. The issue was that in my learnableMove field, I was adding an empty string which when printed using toString() was showing [] whereas the size of the list was 1.